# Typescript - Field Mapping types seem to remove string literals in error checking

Tags: typescript

Apologies up front for quite a convoluted case: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAAjIUwDwBwewE4BcRIJ4wiAykhBLAOwHMA1AQwBsBXLAXhAG8QAiAZzyLKtpYC4QHAiRABfUOGjxkqDFgCShJBGIQEFGvSasiy1ep4R+IQtQC2AIzVjgEsFMQp0mEADF8ESgBMNtEA1xhbk0QAB8QRT01XwhbcEhYR1kXd08fQzZ-bQBtQnIzCAEhLgBdAVTvGJt45ywK9M0AWXIYGC5Mujt4kGzikgAaHE4SGJKwrvjc8ysEQciVaMMSuMlEmVq3D0qMgHkAMwAeABUAPizmCfBsgGsINBAiEFu0OD2QI7KQAFEoPHIAYyQB3qMWarXag2yRxudzG0GUhC8mT6xBAAH5BMNUQJoc8SoNyIQ0CUTtkAIxjLqiADcXS6G0aaCOcnOlzA+C8AlMljUVJAADIQAAKZmYMlhd5yABMAEoVmANqKIOK6Iw2SB-uQ9Ig0AIAOQ7QgQPX9dUcLXUNhc6a8+LiGospVS-xq7rgTXahC6kB6o4AdzgJvV-zgXkKmKCVPlySwRwQhLYe0QBS8jKVWRBu0OabkJ2jIcIHBA5BA5S2DVobH2BxzmDODFdboenKYugWBk0AjJolNTY1WpUOoEjBRMX1huNPeDofDI6xY595As-z19vA4i6BaLFgEtfojbdHK7vabHsHXvHRqDfZDYf1S5XVKAA)

As can seen in the code example - a const of `MyType` value of `One` in the `category` key should have a `status` key, and value of `Two` in `category` should have a `code` key.

When declaring a variable of `MyType`, Typescript can see an error with that object having both `category: 'One'` and `code: 'abc'` entries. This is `const b` in the Playground link.

However, after `MyType` has been put through a transformation type, where any `string` value is mapped to `{stringValue: string}` and `number` value to `{integerValue: number}`, Typescript no longer shows an error for `category: {stringValue: 'One'}` and `code: {stringValue: 'abc'}`. This is `const a` in the Playground link.

Is this intended behaviour? I'm not sure what error I might be making in the transformation mapping.

Full code example also presented below:

```
    export type StringValue = { "stringValue": string }
    export type IntegerValue = { "integerValue": number }

    export type FieldValue = StringValue | IntegerValue

    export type FieldValues = { [name: string]: FieldValue }
    type FieldValueMappings =
        [string, StringValue] |
        [number, IntegerValue]

    export type FieldValuesOf<T> = { 
        [key in keyof T]: Extract<FieldValueMappings, [T[key] extends string ? string : T[key], any]>[1] 
    };
    
    type MyType = {
        id: number
    } & (Type1 | Type2)

    type Type1 ={
        category: 'One',
        status: number
    }
    type Type2 ={
        category: 'Two',
        code: string
    }

    type TransformedMyType = FieldValuesOf<MyType>

    const a : FieldValuesOf<MyType> = {
        id: {integerValue: 1},
        category: {stringValue: 'One'},
        code: {stringValue: 'abc'}
    }

    const b: MyType ={
        id: 1,
        category: 'One',
        code: 'abc'
    }
```

Comment: The issue is that `FieldValuesOf<MyType>` is not a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions); and certainly `a` is a `{  id: IntegerValue;  category: StringValue; code: StringValue; }`.

Comment: Had a read - so `MyType` is a discriminated union, but in `FieldValuesOf<T>` in my mind it maps every key, so it should also map into a discriminated union? How would you be able to map without losing the discriminated union, or is best practice to simply define more types explicitly? Thanks @jcalz, here for every typescript question I had

Comment: Hmm, well I guess the issue isn't exactly that the union isn't discriminated, but that you're losing information you care about.  Both `"One"` and `"Two"` are strings, you are mapping them both to `StringValue`, so the compiler can't tell the difference between them.  Forget about discriminating (sorry), just note that `category: {integerValue: "RandomString"}` is not prohibited.  Maybe [this code](https://tsplay.dev/N9J0Vm) could fare better by preserving specific types?  If that approach works for you I can maybe write up an answer.  Let me know.

Comment: I see what you mean now - because although 'One' and 'Two' are string literals, they `extend string` and therefore get matched to `[string, StringValue<T>]` as if `One` is a not string literal. Hmm. I'll have a think but it does sound like getting into even more complicated mapping rules or having more explicit definitions are my two options here.